# Рандомный выбор python

Tags: python, список

Вообщем, немного не понял, как сделать что бы он выбрал рандомно слот в который ударил, извините за довольно глупый вопрос, новичок в этом, вот код:

```
text += (
                    "☠ После долгой схватки, " + users[0]["first_name"] + " " + users[0]["last_name"] +
                    " и " + (player1.weapon.name.lower() if player1.weapon else " никчемный меч ") + " дoбивают пeрcонaжа "
                    + users[1]["first_name"] + " " + users[1]["last_name"] + " ударом в " + (player2.helm.name.lower() if player2.helm else (player2.tors.name.lower() if player2.tors else "никчемный нагрудник"))
                )
```

Comment: что бы он выбрал одно из тех что там есть if player helm if player tors, если они есть если нет то никчемный меч и тд)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно, вам подойдет [random.choice()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
import random
slots = [ "some helm", "another helm", "yet another helm" ]
print(random.choice(slots))
```

Comment: а можно так сделать slots = [ player1.helm.name.lower() if player1.helm else "Нет" ]
?

Comment: @МихаилГнида, не понял смысла этого действия, ``slots`` можно заполнить любым количеством элементов, доступных для воздействия, не только ``helm``'ом

Comment: Понял спасибо вам большое, извинитн за отнятое время.

Comment: Пожалуйста, но на будущее, уточняйте, пожалуйста, вопросы, как просил Twiss, это облегчает поиск решения.

Comment: Постараюсь, ещё раз огромное спасибо